# What causes MethodAccessException during construction of WindsorContainer?

Tags: castle-windsor-3

What causes MethodAccessException during construction of WindsorContainer?

`` System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.DefaultConfigurationStore..ctor()' to access method 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>..ctor()' failed.
    at Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.DefaultConfigurationStore..ctor()
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.RegisterSubSystems()
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel..ctor(IDependencyResolver resolver, IProxyFactory proxyFactory)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel..ctor()
   at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer..ctor() ``

.NET 4.7.2
Castle.Windsor 3.3.0

Answer (score 7):

Looks like this was because I was attempting to use Castle.Windsor 3.3.0 with Castle.Core.4.4.0.  This will cause [issues](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/issues/224).